# Where do I put Quartz Composer in XCode 4.4

Tags: xcode4.4, quartz-composer

The new  Xcode 4.4 does not include Quartz Composer and is not installed in the folder Macintosh HD / Developer,  but as an app in Applications. Quartz Composer has to download separately from the Apple Developer website. The dmg. Graphics Tools contains a series of tools among them is the QC. My question is: where do I install these Graphics Tools? In the dmg there isn't info about the installation. Any help?
Tnks
Joseph

Answer (score 2):

You can copy the `.app` bundles wherever you like.  I recommend simply copying them to `/Applications`, like any other app bundle.

Answer (score 0):

Put them in the Applications folder in Xcode.app/contents

That way they will appear in the xcode>Open Developer Tools menu